# Convolutional Neural Network for Forecasting Video, 3 Dimensional Data, 2 Spatial Dimensions, 1 Time Dimension, Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, regression, convolutional-neural-network

If we have data with 2D RGB images ordered in time, how can they be fed into a CNN? Are there 4d arrays or something like multidimensional pandas Dataframes compatible with TensorFlow.

The output, I want to be future images that it forecasts. How can I specify this output?

Also, if I want padding for the spatial dimensions, since i want the size of the output pictures to be the same, how can I get padding for solely the spatial dimensions? Also, can padding be customized, so it can be, for example, another part of the image.